# PostgreSQL full text search: How to change what classifies as a "word separator"?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Using `ts_debug` I can see what symbols Postgres treats as (what I call) a "word separator".

Example:

```
SELECT ts_debug('english', 'Hello. ABC')
```

Result:

```
(asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",Hello,{english_stem},english_stem,{hello})
(blank,"Space symbols",". ",{},,)
(asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",ABC,{english_stem},english_stem,{abc})
```

`.` (dot space) is treated as a word separator.
My problem is, I need Postgres to treat a single dot `.` as a word separator too.

Right now, if I search for `ABC` no entry with the content `Hello.ABC` (without space after the dot) will be found, only with `Hello. ABC`.

I am using this search query:

```
SELECT description FROM incident WHERE
  to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'ABC')
```

Another example: Searching for `IOException` will not find `java.io.IOException`

Is there a way to treat a single dot (without space) as a word separator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the parser will recognize `Hello.ABC` as a hostname:

```
SELECT alias, description, token, lexemes FROM ts_debug('english', 'Hello.ABC');
┌───────┬─────────────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ alias │ description │   token   │   lexemes   │
├───────┼─────────────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│ host  │ Host        │ Hello.ABC │ {hello.abc} │
└───────┴─────────────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
(1 row)
```

You'd have to change the parser or create a new one to avoid that, but that can only be done in C.

The workaround that I'd recommend is to replace all dots and slashes with blanks before processing:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english',
          translate('Hello/ABC', '/.', '  ')
       ) @@ to_tsquery('english',
          translate('ABC', '/.', '  ')
       ) AS match;
┌───────┐
│ match │
├───────┤
│ t     │
└───────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: There are so much options to configure Postgres FTS, I thought I could change this easily. But your suggested workaround is fine for my case. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for my sloppiness, fixed.